# problem using microsoft.office.server and microsoft.office.server.userprofiles

Tags: user-profile

I'm trying to retrieve the user profile properties in a webpart so i can display some kind of CV in a new tab on the my sites.

Regarding this tutorial (http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2010/11/01/sharepoint-2010-cookbook-programmers-guide-to-user-profiles.aspx) i need different references. i looked it up and according to msdn they are a part of .NET 4 which i surely have already installed..

are there some references which i have to add manually?

Comment: Can you please explain the specifics of your problem?  Can you not find the files to reference?  Are you getting an error when trying to build with those references?

Comment: i didn't find the files to reference. for me it looked like i just had to use the reference and not add it specifically.. - though i found the files in the meantine ;) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you developing on a system that has SharePoint Server installed?  You need to add the project references to

Microsoft.Office.Server 
Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles

As long as you are on a server with SharePoint Server installed, you will be able to add those references, they are not added by default.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have problems writing your webpart, or is this just an informational question? second: you need the .Net 3.5 runtime, not .Net 4.0

Comment: I have problems writing the webpart because i can't add the necessary references.. and i have .NET 3.5 installed :/